# Dúvida HTML Enviar texto de um inputtext para php

Tags: php, html

Olá estou iniciando em html + php estou com dificuldades em enviar as informações de um campo de texto para meu php.

**segue meu código html.**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>.. Telefone ..:</title>
<h1>Lista de Telefones</h1>
<h2>Informe o Telefone:</h2>
<input type="text" name="nume" onClick="document.formulario.numerotelefone.value =nume">



<form method=post name="formulario" action="executa.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="numerotelefone" value=nume>
 <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
</head>
</html>
```

**segue meu código em php**

```
<?php
    $exibetelefone = $_POST['numerotelefone'];
    echo "Telefone: ".$exibetelefone."<br>";

?>
```

Recebo o texto escrito nume ao invez do número que informei no campo inputtext poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Porque colocar o atributo `value=nume` e o JavaScript `document.formulario.numerotelefone.value =nume`?

Comment: Victor, para entendermos melhor sua necessidade, saberia nos explicar o porque de haver dois inputs para o telefone? Caso não saiba sugiro remover o `input` desnecessário e prosseguir conforme algumas das respostas abaixo.

Comment: eu limpei higiênizei o código estava com 2 inputs realmente estava usando o hidden porque antes estava usando um checkbox achei q o processo era o mesmo estou lendo mais a fundo essa parte é que queria ver se minha ideia funcionaria antes de tentar hehe obrigado pelo retorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor, altere o seu html para isto:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.. Telefone ..:</title>
<h1>Lista de Telefones</h1>
<h2>Informe o Telefone:</h2>
<form method=post name="formulario" action="executa.php">
    <input type="text" name="numerotelefone">
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: deu certinho muito obrigado pela explicação vou me aprofundar mais realmente html e php não entendo nada tentei usar a mesma lógica das outras linguagems apenas atribuindo= e não deu certo

Answer (score 2):

Você está enviando o `'numerotelefone'` através do input hidden com o valor predefinido de nume, através de `value=nume`.

Se você quer digitar o número de telefone, use esse código:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>.. Telefone ..:</title> 
<h1>Lista de Telefones</h1> 
<h2>Informe o Telefone:</h2> 
<form method=post name="formulario" action="executa.php">   
    <input type="text" name="numerotelefone">   
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"> 
</form> 
</head> 
</html>
```

Você estará mudando seu input de hidden (que não aparece na página) para text, dessa forma aparecerá o formulário para você digitar. E agora não está setado um valor pré-determinado com value.

Comment: Entendi, Hegon obrigado pelos detalhes na explicação como mencionei ali em cima eu usei a logica das outras linguagems e atribuir = achei q em html seria o mesmo processo testei aqui deu certo obrigado pelo suporte

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado e boa sorte na sua aprendizagem.

Answer (score 1):

Veja que no input hidden você definiu "nume" como valor para o campo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numerotelefone" value=nume>
```

O `onClick="document.formulario.numerotelefone.value =nume"` no input text vai dar sempre erro, porque a variável `nume` que você está querendo enviar para o campo `numerotelefone` não existe, portanto o valor do input hidden vai ser sempre o mesmo, ou seja, "nume".

Embora não faça muito sentido o que está querendo fazer, você poderia usar `onkeyup` em vez de `onclick` no input text, alterando a forma de enviar o valor desse campo para o input hidden `numerotelefone`:

```
onkeyup="document.formulario.numerotelefone.value = this.value"
```

O `this.value` retorna o valor do próprio campo, e o `onkeyup` é disparado cada vez que você tecla alguma coisa no campo. Em resumo, tudo o que você digitar nesse campo de texto será enviado para o campo hidden que está no formulário.

Como você disse ser iniciante, minha resposta foi para poder explicar os erros, mas o ideal mesmo é fazer como sugere as outras respostas.